# Gravity not applying to my character controller (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a mesh with character controller component. When I run the game it doesn't fall. It stays in the air.

I it worked like one year ago I think. But now I have no idea what to do.

I tried installing new version but still nothing. I went on google but i only found coding tutorials and stuff.

Comment: You need a Rigidbody component on your GameObject for the physics to have any effect on it.

Comment: The character controller doesn't use gravity. You have to explicitly instruct it to move down.

Comment: With rigidbody I don't really get good results, but code thing works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unity Character Controller component doesn't use Gravity by itself.

When you use `CharacterController.SimpleMove()` in your code, it calls Gravity and when you use `CharacterController.Move()` in your code, it doesn't call Gravity.

If you want a codeless solution, your alternatives are either use Rigidbody and collider component instead of character controller, or use a character controller from AssetStore.

You can simply put this code in your `Update` method:

```
    controller.SimpleMove(moveDir);
```

Whereas controller Is Character Controller Component And moveDir Is a Vector3 Variable That Character Wants To Go To

And If You Want To Have Your Own Character Controller With controller.Move You Can Write A Script For Applying Gravity. Here Is An Example Of Implementing Gravity Code:

```
[SerializeField] private CharacterController controller;
[SerializeField] private Vector3 moveDir = new Vector3(0f,0f,0f);
bool grounded = false;
void Update()
{
    Move();
    Gravity();
}
void Move()
{
    controller.Move(moveDir);
}
void Gravity()
{
    moveDir.y += Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;
    var flags = controller.Move(moveDir * Time.deltaTime);
    grounded = ((flags & CollisionFlags.CollidedBelow) != 0);
}
```

Comment: You **REALLY** Must Not Capitalize  Each And Every Single Word In Your English text !